# How do I add a node reference as a apache solr facet

Tags: 7, search

I have used Search API which provided a lot more facets like node reference fields by default as facets. However I had to use solr3.6 and decided to take up ApacheSolr module for this project. I see that it only gives normal cck fields as facets. Do I have to create a custom facet for this?

Comment: This post is flagged as being related to Drupal 7, but there is mention of CCK. The D7 version of Apache Solr Search Integration supports integration with the References and Entity Reference module out-of-the-box. Can you clarify whether this question is indeed related to Drupal 7?

Comment: I have fixed this issue using a sandbox module which integrates entity reference with solr. Apologies for using the terms node reference, cck which is Drupal 6 specific.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I used your sandbox apachesolr entityreference which provided entity reference fields as facets. I am having a problem when I configure the facet with an OR selection enabled. I am not able to find the sandbox project to post it in its issue queue.

Comment: The sandbox project actually got merged into the core Apache Solr Search Integration project. See http://drupal.org/node/1572722 for more details. Therefore the sandbox project is no longer available, and issues should be posted against the core module.